# Will Python 3 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS always be on the 3.6.x branch?

Tags: 18.04, updates, python3, lts

I wanted to ask if the default Python 3 version on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will always be on the Python 3.6.x branch, or might it update to 3.7 in the future?

If it will be updated to 3.7, is there a time frame for this?

Comment: Related: [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)

Answer (score 4):

Since 18.04 is an LTS release, it is unlikely that the Python version that comes with it will be updated to a new major version.

You can install Python 3.7 alongside Python 3.6, if you want, by running:

```
sudo apt install python3.7
```

in a terminal, although, in my opinion, it would be better not to mess with multiple Python versions installed in your system through `apt`, since this could make your system unstable.

Instead, I highly recommend downloading and installing the [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) distribution and use virtual environments managed by `conda` for the different Python versions you need.

Comment: I don't want to install 3.7. I want to make sure the default python 3 version will be 3.6.x, as in the past it was 3.6.5 and now it's 3.6.7.

Comment: As I said, since 18.04 is an LTS release, it is safe to assume that Python will only have minor 3.6.x updates.